The Toastr notification is not woking
i use toastr by Brian2694\Toastr\ToastrServiceProvider::class in my laravel project but now i have a problem is not working after redirect example when i update things i set toastr to show me the success message but is not working only work when i return view not route
toastr()->success('successfuly updated', 'Notification');
redirect()->route('account.financials.collections.portifolios.buildings.show', $results)



but in my layout i have
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-vKMx8UnXk60zUwyUnUPM3HbQo8QfmNx7+ltw8Pm5zLusl1XIfwcxo8DbWCqMGKaWeNxWA8yrx5v3SaVpMvR3CA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-VEd+nq25CkR676O+pLBnDW09R7VQX9Mdiij052gVCp5yVH3jGtH70Ho/UUv4mJDsEdTvqRCFZg0NKGiojGnUCw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

{!! toastr()->message() !!}
    {!! toastr()->clear() !!}


i included the Provider in app.config
'providers' => [
        Brian2694\Toastr\ToastrServiceProvider::class,
]


please help am still not getting solution
